# Issue with shell script replacement

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I've a text file named `a.txt` which has content like below:-

**File Content:**

```
DOMAIN_PRODUCTION = "https://example.com";
DOMAIN_A = "https://example-A.com";
DOMAIN_B = "https://example-B.com";
DOMAIN_LOCAL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
DOMAIN = DOMAIN_A
```

I want to replace certain things with `sed` commands based on some condition. I am able to do it successfully when I use only `1` line in my `if` statement but when I use more than `1` line it is executing only `else` statement though the condition is true.

My Script is something like below:-

```
env=LOCAL
ip=http://127.1.1.2:3000
if [ $env == LOCAL ]
then
   sed 's~DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$~DOMAIN_LOCAL = "'"$ip"'";~' a.txt
   sed 's~DOMAIN = .*$~DOMAIN = '"$env"'~' a.txt
   #  If I comment the above line, my if loop executes, but If I don't, it doesn't execute if statement, though the condition is correct.
else
   sed 's~DOMAIN = .*$~DOMAIN = '"$env"'~' a.txt
fi
```

Output should be something like:-

```
DOMAIN_PRODUCTION = "https://example.com";
DOMAIN_A = "https://example-A.com";
DOMAIN_B = "https://example-B.com";
DOMAIN_LOCAL = "http://127.1.1.2:3000"; # Changed here
DOMAIN = DOMAIN_LOCAL # Changed here
```

It should ideally replace the value of `DOMAIN_LOCAL` and `DOMAIN` but when I use two statements in the `if` loop, it doesn't execute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `env=LOCAL` followed by `if [ $env == LOCAL ]` should _always_ return true, there seems to be no shell script conditional logic happening at all.

Comment: yeah this env here is hardcoded but in actual it is taken by the user so that can be ignored.

Comment: FYI `[ $env == LOCAL ]` should be `[ "$env" = LOCAL ]` Quotes and single equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands seem to work find. The problem with your `sed` commands is that they will just `echo`. You need to substitute the change in file.

```
#!/bin/bash

env=LOCAL
ip=http://127.1.1.2:3000
if [ $env == LOCAL ]
then
   sed -i.bak 's~DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$~DOMAIN_LOCAL = "'$ip'";~' a.txt
   sed -i.bak 's~DOMAIN = .*$~DOMAIN = '"$env"'~' a.txt
   #  Now this will make a backuo of the original file and write changes back to a.txt
else
   sed 's~DOMAIN = .*$~DOMAIN = '"$env"'~' a.txt
fi
```

This will make the needed changes inside "a.txt".

Comment: What is I only want to replace the first occurence in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the 2 `sed` command into one

```
   sed 's~DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$~DOMAIN_LOCAL = "'"$ip"'";~; s~DOMAIN = .*$~DOMAIN = '"$env"'~' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
   sed 's~DOMAIN_LOCAL = .*$~DOMAIN_LOCAL = "'"$ip"'";~' a.txt
```

writes to stdout.
When it is finished, you are starting again with the original, unchanged, a.txt.
The output of the second statement is the same as the command in the else-clause:

```
   sed 's~DOMAIN = .*$~DOMAIN = '"$env"'~' a.txt
```

You can combine the two sed statements in any of the following methods:

```
   sed 'sed1' a.txt | sed 'sed2'
   sed -e 'sed1' -e 'sed2' a.txt
   sed 'sed1;sed2' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think awk is better suited for this:

```
% cat gen.awk
ip && $1 == "DOMAIN_LOCAL" {$3 = '"' ip '"'}
dm && $1 == "DOMAIN" {$3 = dm}
1
```

And all together:

```
env=LOCAL
ip=http://127.1.1.2:3000

if [ "$env" = LOCAL ]; then
   awk -v ip="$ip" -v dm="$env" -f gen.awk a.txt
else
   awk -v dm="$env" -f gen.awk a.txt
fi
```

This will however not do inplace editing. But you can redirect the if statement and use `mv`:

```
if ...; then
    ...
fi > a.txt.out
mv a.txt.out a.txt
```

This works with we set variable to the `gen.awk` script when we run awk:

```
awk -v variable1=value1
```

And in the script we replace third column with that variable if it's set and the first column in that line matches:

```
ip && $1 == "DOMAIN_LOCAL" { $3 = '"' ip '"' }
```

Breakdown:

```
ip                   # If ip is set and not blank
&&                   # ... and ...
$1 == "DOMAIN_LOCAL" # If first column equal DOMAIN_LOCAL
{ $3 = '"' ip '"' }  # Set third column to be "ip" (the variable, with quotes around)
```

The `1` simple prints each line.

Comment: how did you reach the conclusion that awk is better suited and not sed?

Comment: @DisplayName Because you can reuse the script for both cases. See update with a little bit of breakdown. And IMHO it's easier to read and maintain.